# $window.jQuery is undefined in a 3party module, but not window.jQuery

Tags: angularjs, webpack

In my webpack-es6-angularjs app I struggle with a problem where I could need some help: When trying to load a 3rd-party library, the 3rd-party library raises an error, that jQuery is undefined even though jQuery is exposed through webpack.

```
//webpack.config.js
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
})
```

The 3rd-party library uses jQuery through `!$window.jQuery.support...` but `$window.jQuery` does not exist – NOTE the extra `$` from angularjs – where as `window.jQuery` exists as expected form the webpack config.

monkey-patching the 3rd-party library works but of course is to no solution. Any idea where this can come from and how this could be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I was able to solve it by explicitly injecting jQuery into the angularjs $window object:

```
import * as jquery from 'jquery';
import { IWindowService } from 'angular';

function jQueryService($window: IWindowService): any {
  $window['jQuery'] = jQuery;

  return jquery;
};

jQueryService.$inject = ['$window'];


export default jQueryService;
```